# How do I segment a document using Tesseract then output the resulting bounding boxes and labels

Tags: ocr, tesseract, hocr

I'm trying to get Tesseract to output a file with labelled bounding boxes that result from page segmentation (pre OCR). I know it must be capable of doing this 'out of the box' because of the results shown at the ICDAR competitions where contestants had to segment and various documents ([academic paper here](http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/www/assets/papers/ICDAR2013_Antonacopoulos_HNLA2013.pdf)). Here's an example from that paper illustrating what I want to create:
[image: Image of segmented and labelled output]

I have built the latest version of tesseract using brew, `brew install tesseract --HEAD`, and have been trying to edit config files located in `/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/HEAD/share/tessdata/configs/` to output labelled boxes. The output received using `hocr` as the config, i.e.

```
tesseract infile.tiff outfile_stem -l eng -psm 1 hocr
```

gives a bounding box for everything and has some labelling in `class` tags e.g.

```
<p class='ocr_par' dir='ltr' id='par_5_82' title="bbox 2194 4490 3842 4589">
    <span class='ocr_line' id='line_5_142' ...
```

but I can't visualise this. Is there a standard tool to visualize hOCR files, or is the facility to create an output file with bounding boxes built into Tesseract?

The current head version details:

```
tesseract 3.04.00
 leptonica-1.71
  libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.16 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.5
```

---

### Edit

I'm really looking to achieve this using the command line tool (as in examples above). @nguyenq has pointed me to the [API reference](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample), unfortunately I have no c++ experience. If the only solution is to use the API, please can you provide a quick python example?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Success. Many thanks to the people at the [Pattern Recognition and Image Analysis Research Lab (PRImA)](http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/) for producing tools to handle this. You can obtain them freely on their [website](http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/tools) or [github](https://github.com/PRImA-Research-Lab).

Below I give the full solution for a Mac running 10.10 and using the [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager. I use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) to run windows executables.

### Overview

1. Download tools: [Tesseract OCR to Page](http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/tools/TesseractOCRToPAGE) (TPT) and [Page Viewer](http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/tools/PAGEViewer) (PVT)
2. Use the TPT to run tesseract on your document and convert the HOCR xml to a PAGE xml
3. Use the PVT to view the original image with the PAGE xml information overlaid

### Code

```bash
brew install wine  # takes a little while >10m
brew install gs    # only for generating a tif example. Not required, you can use Preview
brew install wget  # only for downloading example paper. Not required, you can do so manually!
cd ~/Downloads
wget -O paper.pdf "http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/www/assets/papers/ICDAR2013_Antonacopoulos_HNLA2013.pdf"
# This command can be ommitted and you can do the conversion to tiff with Preview
gs                          \
  -o paper-%d.tif           \
  -sDEVICE=tiff24nc         \
  -r300x300                 \
   paper.pdf 

cd ~/Downloads
# ttptool is the location you downloaded the Tesseract to PAGE tool to
ttptool="/Users/Me/Project/tools/TesseractToPAGE 1.3"
# sudo chmod 777 "$ttptool/bin/PRImA_Tesseract-1-3-78.exe"
touch "$ttptool/log.txt"
wine "$ttptool/bin/PRImA_Tesseract-1-3-78.exe"   \
  -inp-img "$dl/Downloads/paper-3.tif"           \
  -out-xml "$dl/Downloads/paper-3-tool.xml"      \
  -rec-mode layout>>log.txt

# pvtool is the location you downloaded the PAGE Viewer tool to
pvtool="/Users/Me/Project/tools/PAGEViewerMacOS_1.1/JPageViewer 1.1 (Mac OS, 64 bit)"
cd "$pvtool"
dl=~
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar JPageViewer.jar "$dl/Downloads/paper-3-tool.xml" "$dl/Downloads/paper-3.tif"
```

### Results

Document with overlays (rollover to see text and type)
[image: Doc with overlays]
Overlays alone (use GUI buttons to toggle)
[image: Overlays alone]

### Appendix

You can run tesseract yourself and use another tool to convert its output to PAGE format. I was unable to get this to work but I'm sure you'll be fine!

```
# Note that the pvtool does take as input HOCR xml but it ignores the region type
brew install tesseract --devel  # installs v 3.03 at time of writing
tesseract ~/Downloads/paper-3.tif ~/Downloads/paper-3 hocr
mv paper-3.hocr paper-3.xml  # The page viewer will only open XML files
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar JPageViewer.jar "$dl/Downloads/paper-3.xml"
```

At this point you need to use the [PAGE Converter Java Tool](http://www.prima.cse.salford.ac.uk/tools/PAGEConverterValidator) to convert the HOCR xml into a PAGE xml. It should go a little something like this:

```
pctool="/Users/Me/Project/tools/JPageConverter 1.0"
java -jar "$pctool/PageConverter.jar" -source-xml paper-3.xml -target-xml paper-3-hocrconvert.xml -convert-to LATEST
```

Unfortunately, I kept getting null pointers.

```
Could not convert to target XML schema format.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primaresearch.dla.page.converter.PageConverter.run(PageConverter.java:126)
    at org.primaresearch.dla.page.converter.PageConverter.main(PageConverter.java:65)
Could not save target PAGE XML file: paper-3-hocrconvert.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primaresearch.dla.page.io.xml.XmlInputOutput.writePage(XmlInputOutput.java:144)
    at org.primaresearch.dla.page.converter.PageConverter.run(PageConverter.java:135)
    at org.primaresearch.dla.page.converter.PageConverter.main(PageConverter.java:65)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use its API to obtain the bounding boxes at various levels (character/word/line/para) -- see [API Example](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample). You have to draw the labels yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is there no way to do this using the command line tool?

Comment: The hocr produced by the command-line gives you the word-level resolution. Other than that, you will have to go against the API.

Answer (score 4):

If you are python familiar, you can directly use `tesserocr` library which is a nice python wrapper around the C++ API. Here is a code snippet to draw polygons at block level using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL, iterate_level, PSM

img = Image.open(filename)

results = []
with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    api.SetImage(img)
    api.SetPageSegMode(PSM.AUTO_ONLY)
    iterator = api.AnalyseLayout()
    for w in iterate_level(iterator, RIL.BLOCK):
        if w is not None:
            results.append((w.BlockType(), w.BlockPolygon()))
print('Found {} block elements.'.format(len(results)))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for block_type, poly in results:
    # you can define a color per block type (see tesserocr.PT for block types list)
    draw.line(poly + [poly[0]], fill=(0, 255, 0), width=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

With Tesseract 4.0.0, a command like `tesseract source/dir/myimage.tiff target/directory/basefilename hocr` will create a `basefilename.hocr` file with block-, paragraph-, line-, and word-level bounding boxes for the OCR'ed text.  Even the command without the `hocr` config creates a text file with newlines between block-level text, but the hocr format is more explicit.

More config options here:  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/master/tessdata/configs

Answer (score 2):

**Shortcut**

It is also possible to open HOCR files directly with the PageViewer tool. The file extension has to be .xml, however.

Comment: It's hidden away, but I mention this in the 'Appendix' of my answer. Opening HOCR straight from tesseract shows a file with only 'paragraph' regions, i.e. region types are ignored. Is this expected?

Comment: I'm not managing to get this to work. Whether I open an `out.hocr` or an `out.xml`, I get this message from PageViewer: `An XML loading error occured. Please ensure XML validity and try again.` (I produced the `out.xml` by renaming `out.xml`--should I be doing something different?)

Answer (score 0):

The HOCR individual character step is now available in Tesseract since 4.1.
Once the installation check, use :

`tesseract {image file} {output name} -c tessedit_create_hocr=1 -c hocr_char_boxes=1`