# Tesseract OCR to PAGE

Tags: ocr, tesseract

The tool Tesseract OCR to PAGE [located here](http://www.primaresearch.org/tools) is a Windows tool to run tesseract and output a file in page format (an xml file that contains structural information about the document). Do you know of any mac version of this kind of tool?

This question is linked to my previous: [How do I segment a document then output bounding boxes and labels using tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591117/how-do-i-segment-a-document-then-output-bounding-boxes-and-labels-using-tesserac)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this tool using `wine` an example is included in my answer to the question linked in the question.