# Trying to do OCR with on mac using Tesseract OCR to Page (TPT) and Page Viewer (PVT) and Aletheia software

Tags: java, macos, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use Aletheia and tesseract-orc with some images in mac. But I faced many problems:

1. I can't make Aletheia work with wine, it just doesn't open
2. I followed the instruction of the question [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591117/how-do-i-segment-a-document-using-tesseract-then-output-the-resulting-bounding-b/34160636#34160636) but I've got this result regarding the use of Tesseract OCR to Page (TPT) and Page Viewer (PVT):

   ```
   $ java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar JPageViewer.jar "$dl/Downloads/paper-3-tool.xml" "$dl/Downloads/paper-3.tif"
   2015-12-08 18:53:34.327 java[33741:1234051] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
   2015-12-08 18:53:34.336 java[33741:1234051] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead. 
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/primaresearch/dla/page/layout/physical/shared/ContentType : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
       at org.primaresearch.page.viewer.ui.MainWindow.init(MainWindow.java:51)
       at org.primaresearch.page.viewer.PageViewer.<init>(PageViewer.java:79)
       at org.primaresearch.page.viewer.PageViewer.main(PageViewer.java:50)
   ```

   Any suggestions?? Sorry, If I put the question in the wrong place before. Thanks!!

Comment: Seems you are using an outdated version of a lib which causes incompatibilities.

Comment: Ok, How can I fix it?? I've updated to the latest Java version, and I've also tried with the jar-launcher of my mac, but it retrieves error. I don't know why I can't open .jar files