# Tesseract - [Japanese] Vertical text with horizontal numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm having trouble with vertical text mixed with horizontal numbers.

For example:

[image: Text]

If that was a single digit it would've been successful but tesseract tries to read this number as a single character since it expects characters to come vertically. I know tesseract gives a confidence factor for the whole sentence and not for every character. 
Is there a way to identify low confidence on this character only and try something different on it to correctly parse the numbers?

Comment: Are you using jpn_vert.traineddata?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that, it reads the "24" part as one character

Comment: I don't know about the confidence part, but you might address that as a separate question. Like "high confidence" do A, "low confidence" do B, rather than focus on a specific example.

Comment: You might also look into page segmentation, to separate the numbers from the kanji. Something like in [How do I segment a document using Tesseract then output the resulting bounding boxes and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591117/how-do-i-segment-a-document-using-tesseract-then-output-the-resulting-bounding-b), though it's far beyond anything I've done.