# Set default column count

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, image-segmentation, cloud-document-ai

I've got a large number of 3- and 6-column journal and newspaper pages that I want to OCR. I want to automate recognition of columns.

I've used `tesseract` ([see a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484514/define-multiple-columns-in-tesseract-ocr-parameters)) and Google Cloud Document AI (using the R package [daiR](https://dair.info/)) without great success.

These programs read the text very well, but do not do a good job of recognizing the column format of pages.

Here's a couple of examples from **daiR**:

[image: image of text blocks on newspaper]

[image]

Obviously these are complex images with some double columns and some tables inside columns. What I want is for the OCR to *try* to look for 6 columns.

I get good results if I preprocess images (for instance by cropping them into single columns or adding vertical lines), but I haven't found an efficient way to do this in large batches. Is there a way of preprocessing images or telling OCR programs to look for a given number of columns?

Comment: can you please post the **original input images** before passing them to *daiR*

Comment: Yes, they are on github: [p4](https://github.com/dig-eg-gaz/page-images/raw/master/1893-page-images-1/1893-01-02-p4.jpg) and [p3](https://github.com/dig-eg-gaz/page-images/raw/master/1893-page-images-1/1893-01-02-p3.jpg)

Comment: FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)

---

Document AI doesn't support searching for a specific number of columns.